# Is it true that $\text{If Pr$(\alpha)=1$, then $\alpha\equiv\top$}$

Tags: probability, logic

Here are some rules, let $\alpha,\beta$ be well-formed formulas, that
$$\begin{align}
&1.~\Pr(\alpha)\ge0\tag*{Non-negativity}\\
&2.~\Pr(\alpha)=1 \text{ if }\alpha\text{ is logically true}\tag*{Normalization}\\
&3.~\Pr(\alpha\lor\beta)=\Pr(\alpha)+\Pr(\beta)\text{ if }\alpha\land\beta\text{ is logically false}\tag*{Additivity}
\end{align}$$
The Normalization says if $\alpha\equiv\top$, then Pr$(\alpha)=1$. Is the converse of this follows from $1,2$ and $3$ ? i.e.
$$\text{If Pr$(\alpha)=1$, then $\alpha\equiv\top$}$$
I'm not sure if it's true, and I can't find a proof of it that use those rules, could someone give me a little hint ?

Comment: Try using the `\Pr` command that’s built into [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). For example, `\Pr x` gives $\Pr x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For example, if $X$ is a random variable with a continuous distribution, then for each possible value $x$, $\Pr(X = x) = 0$ and $\Pr(X \ne x) = 1$.  But $X \ne x$ is
not "logically true".  In fact, the random variable must have some value, so
there must be some real $x$ such that $X=x$.  It's just that any particular $x$ has probability $0$ of being that value.